# PlatformException(connect_errd or timeout)

Tags: flutter, printing, bluetooth, thermal-printer, bluetooth-printing

Title: Issue with Flutter Blue Thermal Printer Package on Oppo Devices

I'm currently facing an issue with the Flutter Blue Thermal Printer package (blue_thermal_printer) on Oppo devices. The package works perfectly fine on Vivo mobile devices, but when attempting to print from an Oppo device, it fails to print. Both devices are running on Android 9.

I've ensured that the necessary permissions are granted, and Bluetooth is enabled on the Oppo device. Despite this, printing still doesn't work.

Is there a known compatibility issue with Oppo devices and the Flutter Blue Thermal Printer package? If so, are there any workarounds or solutions available to resolve this issue?

Any insights or assistance on how to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!